# Why is this increment on every click not working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make an increment on every click, however I am stuck with this original code:

```
$('.de img').click(function() {
            scroll = $('body').scrollTop();
            imgJump = $(this).prevAll().length;
        var $this = $(this),
            bigImgs = $('.biggie:hidden').find('img:hidden');
            console.log(bigImgs[imgJump]);
        $('.de').fadeOut(400, function () {
                $('body').scrollTop(0);
                $('.biggie').fadeIn(400);
            });

        $(bigImgs[imgJump]).fadeIn(400);
        $('.biggietext').fadeIn(400);
        $('.number').text(imgJump + 1);
}); 

$('.biggie img').click(function(){
    var imgIs = imgJump + 1,
        imgIss = imgIs++;

    if ($(this).nextAll().length > 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).next().fadeIn(400);
        });
        $('.number').text(imgIss);                  
        }
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle with an easier version: http://jsfiddle.net/nU63B/3/.

Why is this not working?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show your HTML also? Because as mentioned by user1671639, as per the fiddle markup your if statement will not get executed and hence increment doesn't happen.

Comment: @Harry I changed the fiddle, did not boil it down enough first!! I think the problem is in the `+1` addition and then the following increment.

Comment: The increment works in your updated fiddle (albeit twice, because you have a +1 and a ++).

Comment: @Harry The update only goes once, on the second click it is stuck on 3!!

Comment: It doesn't get updated because you are setting the original value to 1 during every click event. You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nU63B/4/) way.

Comment: Arrhh, I see, try to implement now!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't get increment because your **`if satement`** is not getting executed

```
if ($(this).nextAll().length > 0) { // $(this).nextAll().length 
                                    //returns 0 and hence not working
```

You have only one element (**`p`** tag) and there is is no sibilings associated with it and therefore its length returns 0.

> **`nextAll()`** Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

change it to

```
if ($(this).nextAll().length == 0) {
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nU63B/2/)

Comment: I changed the fiddle, this part was an absolute fail (in the fiddle). ;) Please check it out again, I think the mistake in jQuery is happening at incrementing a value, which was added `+1`?! Or?

Comment: @dollarvar `var imgIs = 1 //returns 1
        imgIss = imgIs + 1; // returns 2
  imgIss++; //returns 3`  hence the final value gets 3

Comment: Wow, this is meticulous!

Comment: @dollarvar in your fiddle,  `imgIs` is always reinitialized to `1` and hence always 3 and check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nU63B/5/

Comment: I see, that`s why I was stuck...I need to update a global variable, which never changes. ;)